# How to reference a post's whole content (including layout) in Jekyll/Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I am using Jekyll (3.0+) and I have my `index.html`:

```
---
layout: mylayout
---
<div>
  {{ site.posts[0].content }}
</div>
```

As you can see I am trying to display only the first post and `_layouts/mylayout.html` is:

```
<article itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <header>
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
  </header>
  <div>
    {{ content }}
  </div>
</article>
```

#### The layout is not included

The problem is that I cannot see the wrapping structure of `mylayout.html`, I can see just the content markdown translation! So, I would have expected:

```
<article itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <header>
    <h1>Page title</h1>
  </header>
  <div>
    <section>My post paragraph</section>
    <p>Hello, this is my post.</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

But I got this:

```
<div>
  <section>My post paragraph</section>
  <p>Hello, this is my post.</p>
</div>
```

How can I refer to the whole page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I need to use `output` property:

```
---
layout: mylayout
---
<div>
  {{ site.posts[0].output }}
</div>
```

This will basically return the whole HTML including the template!

Comment: Unfortunately, because the layout of the post (_post.html_) usually inherits from the _default.html_ layout that usually contains the HTML head, header, and footer (so that it generates a valid HTML page for the single post), and the layout of the _index.html_ page also inherits from the _default.html_ layout, using _post.output_ will generate an invalid HTML file with two HTML heads, headers, footers - one from _index.html_ => _default.html_ layout, and one from _post_html_ => _default.html_ layout.